# Unable to find attribute android:font

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

Get the following error when building a project with PhoneGap Build after adding the cordova-background-geolocation-lt plugin:

```
:processArmv7DebugResourcesERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font  
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle  
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight  

 FAILED  

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  

* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugResources'.  
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt  

* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  

BUILD FAILED  

Total time: 4.171 secs  
Error: /gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:  
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.  
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.  
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font  
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle  
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight  


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  

* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':processArmv7DebugResources'.  
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt  

* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)  
  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)  
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)  
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)  
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

My config.xml looks like this (redacted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id=“[..]” versionCode="[..]" versionName="[..]" version="[..]">  
    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-7.0.1' />  
    <name>[..]</name>  
    <description>[..]</description>  
    <author href="[..]" email="[..]">[..]</author>  
    <content src="index.html" />  
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" />  
    <preference name="FullScreen" value="false" />  
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />  
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />  
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>  
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />  
    <platform name="android">  
        <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false" />  
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />  
        <gap:config-file parent="/manifest/application">  
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  
        </gap:config-file>  
        <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />  
        <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />  
        <preference name="CodePushDeploymentKey" value="[..]" />  
    </platform>  
    <feature name="Device">  
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />  
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />  
    </feature>  
    <feature name="File">  
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />  
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />  
    </feature>  
    <feature name="FileTransfer">  
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />  
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />  
    </feature>  
    <!-- Cordova plugins -->  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.1">  
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="[..]" />  
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="[..]" />  
    </plugin>  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="1.1.2" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.3">  
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="[..]" />  
    </plugin>  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="1.3.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="1.2.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="2.1.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="2.2.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" source="npm" version="v1.4.1" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" version="3.2.2" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="2.1.3" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="1.5.1" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="4.2.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" source="npm" version="0.8.5" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-code-push" source="npm" version="v1.9.3-beta" />  
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" source="npm" version="v2.2.0" />  
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm" version="5.0.0" />  
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" spec="3.1.1" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="~2.3.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email" source="npm" version="1.1.1" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appavailability" spec="^0.4.2" />  
    <plugin name="com.xmartlabs.cordova.market" spec="https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.1.8" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation-lt" source="npm" version="2.8.5" />  
</widget>
```

This problem has been encounted before:

- https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/507
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982/2
- [unable to find attribute android:font for v7 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062650/unable-to-find-attribute-androidfont-for-v7-support)
- https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/116
- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2405676

The generally accepted advice is that `com.android.support:support-v4:27` is causing the problem, so if you have `com.android.support:support-v4:+`, then you should specify `com.android.support:support-v4:23.+`.

However, I haven't got this to work as of yet. I've tried to adding this line:

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:23+" value="gradle" />
```

But that doesn't seem to have an effect for me.

I have cross posted this on the plugins issue tracker: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/563

And on the PhoneGap Build forum: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10028062

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you do to resolve this in the end?

Comment: I stopped using PhoneGap Build unfortunately.

Comment: And what do you use now?