# Updating support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 causes error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''

Tags: android, gradle

I m using [PushIO](https://github.com/pushio/PushIOManager_Android) for use Oracle Push IO service for notification. Because this library using "jobintentservice", So for resolve that dependency I have need to update the buildToolsVersion 26+.
After an update the buildToolsVersion to 26.0.2 I got the error.

```
Error:(251, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''.
```

I must use the buildToolsVersion 26+. so please do not suggest to downgrade the buildToolsVersion at 25+.
Can anyone help me out there to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062650/unable-to-find-attribute-androidfont-for-v7-support

Comment: Try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775778/5022618