# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. error

Tags: react-native

I'm still getting this error
Any help

> Configure project :react-native-video
>   WARNING: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

```
C:\Users\samer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\baf3c48561ce2e3bea1e7fa768dc04ed\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\samer\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\baf3c48561ce2e3bea1e7fa768dc04ed\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 2s 61 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 60 up-to-date
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
>   details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device
>   connected and have set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Cordova/Ionic folks: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654226/ionic-cordova-app-stopped-compiling-after-googles-june-17th-firebase-sdk-update/56656680#56656680) for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to change your build.gradle :

change the compileSdkVersion to: `compileSdkVersion = 28

look at:

[error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208772/error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found)

[unable to find attribute android:font for v7 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062650/unable-to-find-attribute-androidfont-for-v7-support)

---

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/207

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/205#issuecomment-371669478

Comment: I tried to change the compileSdkVersion to: `compileSdkVersion = 28, and I got this error
Execution failed for task ':react-native-video:generateDebugRFile'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\gitLab\fallapp\node_modules\react-native-video\android-exoplayer\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\brentvatne'.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is like at fers490's answer but his answer didn't work for me and the following DID work:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
         force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    }
}
```

Make sure to put it in the correct gradle file.

Comment: where should i add ?

Comment: In android folder gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is caused by a breaking release in google libraries: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

We managed to solve it by forcing updated libraries resolution to previous versions in the build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
         force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
         force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
         force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: You could manually check your dependencies versions using `gradle app:dependencies` and see which ones are using the versions released yesterday. Those are the ones you should try to override.