# Ionic Cordova app stopped compiling after Google's June 17th Firebase SDK update

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm unable to compile Ionic Cordova App after Firebase Major version update with Breaking Changes, specifically with June 17, 2019 update.

I tried downgrading to Android Cordova 6.3.0 but my project must be 7.0.0.

This is my ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.1
    npm               : 5.5.1
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Development\android-sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

This is the error I'm Getting:

> :app:processDebugResources
>   C:\Users\mmzep.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\73b4a83ab5e76f20c84a66b1c8444d08\res\values\values.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> C:\Users\mmzep.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\73b4a83ab5e76f20c84a66b1c8444d08\res\values\values.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> C:\Users\mmzep\Desktop\mario\Seven\SevenPassengerApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:95:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   C:\Users\mmzep\Desktop\mario\Seven\SevenPassengerApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:95:
>   error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking
>   references.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This build failure is due to a [major version release of the Google Play Services and Firebase libaries](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) on June 17.

The new library versions have the following requirements:

> - Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
> - Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.
> - Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX)

The first two requirements can be resolved by updating to use `cordova-android@8.0.0`.

The third requires that your Android project migrates to using AndroidX (Jetpack).
[AndroidX](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx) is the successor to the widely-used [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index). 
AndroidX now used by the latest versions of Play Services/Firebase libraries and the Support library is used by many existing plugins such as [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase).
The two libraries cannot live side-by-side in the same Android build - doing so will lead to build failure.

To resolve this issue, add the following two plugins your Cordova project:

- [cordova-plugin-androidx](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx) to enable AndroidX in the Android project.
- [cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter) to dynamically patch the source code of any plugins using the Support Library to use the AndroidX equivalents.

For a working example of how to try this out in a test project, see [my comment on this Github issue](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1081#issuecomment-503135862).

**Note:** if you are using [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) and encountering errors, you can instead use [my fork of that plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase) which is published as `cordova-plugin-firebasex` and is fixed to resolve issues caused by the new Firebase SDK:

```
rm -Rf platforms/android
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
rm -Rf plugins/ node_modules/
npm install
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: I had a working project so I had to remove the plugins directory `-rf ./plugins` and re add the android plaform `ionic cordova platform rm android` `ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0` and then @DaveAlden solution worked perfectly.

Comment: You're a life saver, your solution worked magically after spending hours trying to revert back to previous version.  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried this but I am not able to get the token from fcm build is successfull my project is on critical condtion @DanielGoncalves I want you help please can you help me my skype id is: ionic.fiverr

Comment: @KishanOza could you add me to your GitHub repository maybe i can have a look at your project username > dan62

Comment: Sure its in bitbucket so give me ur email @DanielGoncalves

Comment: Having the same issue, but unfortunately I am working with Capacitor, not with Cordova. Already had firebasex plugin installed, and also the androidx plugins installed. Any help?

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. First Answer

[We](https://www.wizpanda.com/) have created a PR for this https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/pull/13 but that requires upgrade of `cordova-android` to `8.0.0`.

A workaround is being done for `cordova-android` 7.x but meanwhile, a discussion is also ongoing whether to keep support for it or not.

### 2. Edit - Jun 19, 2019

A new version **v3.3.0** is released to fix the issue caused by Google Firebase release which supports `cordova-android <= 7.1.4`. https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/pull/14#issuecomment-503499409

```sh
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
# Or if you were using original fork
#cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0
```

### 3. Edit - Jun 20, 2019

A new version **v4.0.1** is released to fix the issue caused by Google Firebase release which supports `cordova-android >= 8.0.0`. https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/pull/14#issuecomment-503499409

```sh
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
# Or if you were using original fork
#cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
```

Answer (score 5):

Having in platform/android/project.properties following settings :

```
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/app-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
```

I had the same issue (error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found).

cordova-android@8.0.0 + cordova-plugin-androidx + cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter worked for me perfectly.

Thanks for this solution.

I am just wondering if it is a good long time bet to use those two plugins. Any opinion ?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the sequence below for cordova-android <= 7.1.4

cordova platform remove android
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0
cordova platform add android

## cordova-plugin-firebase is now included in cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

Comment: You should get a lot more upvotes. The easiest solution I found that fixes the problem.

Comment: Absolutely best answer! So easy and it actually worked!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try to add in your build-extras.gradle, inside the platform/android folder of your project this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
         force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
         force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    }
}
```

In this way you will **force** the build command to **ignore the updates** and to use the previous versions.
You don't even need to change any plugin (nor the android platform version)!

*Every time firebase's libs are updated this happens.. and it is very annoying. I'd love to be able to turn off the auto dependency update on build command, but I don't think it is possible.*

Answer (score 2):

```
ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0
```

(if you removed this npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase@4 install again)

There was a **dex merger** issue in android 7.0.0 for me. So I have used **android 8.0.0**

To use android 8.0.0

```
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0

if required install below 2 plugin for android 8.0.0

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
```

and

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps if you have tried everything and you cannot build your cordova android project yet.**

I've been working on this issue for five days and this is the only solution that works for me (it's a recopilation of solutions and comments, ordered in the sequence I followed to make my projects work):

1. **Install the latest cordova version** (cordova@9.0.0):

   npm install -g cordova
2. **Create a new blank cordova project** (use the same reverse domain and project name):

   cordova create folderName com.projectName.app projectName
3. **Add the latest cordova-android platform** (cordova-android@8.0.0):

   cordova platform add android
4. **Install every plugin that appears on your original project (except cordova-plugin-firebase)**. I would recomend you to build your app after each plugin installation to check if everything is OK.
5. **Install cordova-plugin-firebase-lib**

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
6. **Install cordova-plugin-androidx**

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
7. **Install cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter**

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
8. **Copy the firebase settings files to the root of your project**: google-services.json for Android and GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS
9. **Copy resources tags** (for icons and splash screens) from your *old* config.xml and paste them into your new config.xml.

```html
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/android/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/android/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/android/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="180" src="res/ios/icon/1024x1024.png" width="1024" />
    <icon height="180" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-60x60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="60" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-20x20@3x.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-40x40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-76x76@1x.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-76x76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-20x20@2x.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-40x40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-29x29@2x.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-29x29@1x.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/ios/icon/Icon-29x29@2x.png" width="58" />
</platform>
```

10. **Copy your *old* res folder to the root of your project** (the folder that has all your icons and splash screens).
11. **Replace the content of your new /www folder** with the content of the original one.
12. **Finally, build your project**

    cordova build android

In my case, I had two plugins that were in conflict with the new cordova, cordova-android, firebase sdk versions: **cordova-plugin-firebase** and **cordova-plugin-locationservices**, and **these steps let me continue with my projects.**

Answer (score -1):

Here are the exact steps I did to fix

```
cordova build android
```

delete platforms folder

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
cordova build android
ionic cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
ionic cordova emulate
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution :
Follow the sequence below for
 cordova android platform <= 7.1.4

cordova platform remove android
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0
cordova platform add android