# Why is the flutter command, "flutter run --release" not working?

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have built an application using sharedpreferences so i could track who is logged in and logged out the app, but some reason, when i run the command "flutter run --release" it is giving off this error, I know one of them is referring directly to how I am using SharedPreferences, but I don't know how to fix it. Could some please help me?

[Image of the error being displayed in my console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekqhT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
flutter clean
```

then try this your command.
If the problem isn't solved let me know

Answer (score 0):

First run android folder in your project with android studio and sync it.

> And try to change the compileSdkVersion to: `compileSdkVersion 28` or upper

And to get more information you can see this posts : [this](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/207) a,d [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062650/unable-to-find-attribute-androidfont-for-v7-support)

Comment: Could you please explain how to do thiS?

Comment: In your project folder there are lib,android and ios and ... open this android folder with your android studio @MichaelCabusas